# Java Can the same event be triggerd multiple times and be running at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, events, event-dispatch-thread

If I have a MouseMotionListener, will multiple mouseDragged methods get executed and have the possibility of being running concurrently? Here is a picture:

```
    Time -> 0------------1---------------2------------------------3-------------------------------4------
            Mouse Moved--mouseDragged()--Method crunches numbers--Method Still Crunching Numbers--Method keeps doing stuff
                                         Mouse Moved--------------mouseDragged()------------------Starts to do stuff
```

OR:

```
Mouse Moved
mouseDragged()
Stuff happens
Mouse Moved again but nothing happens
More stuff happens
Stuff done
mouseDragged()
Stuff
Done
```

You should get the idea. Thanks!

I know about the EDT, but not sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) does not say anything about concurrent invocation of `mouseDragged/mouseMoved` method. I believe it's being called sequential. It would be very non-intuitive if `i+1`-th invocation of `mouseDragged/mouseMoved` callback gets finished while `i`-th is still processing